# Search in mysql without special symbols when mysql row with special symbols?

Tags: mysql, search, special-characters

```
Search input: How to format 
Mysql row: How to - Format
```

How can I find "How to - Format" if search input is "How to format"?

In other words how can I search in mysql without special symbols when mysql row with special symbols?

Sorry for my English and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a replace on the column you're searching within - at which point all chances of using indexes are lost.  Best bet it to enable full-text indexing (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)) and not worry about punctuation etc.  Another option is to ensure when you insert data into the table, you have an additional "punctuationless" column and search on that instead - but full-text search is almost certainly the way to go.